# Loading images and songs with nonce

Tags: php, jquery, css, nonce

I am currently working on a stand-alone slideshow app, which shows CSS-animated images together with music.

Up to today, images and music were just loaded directly from their real location - meaning that this location and the files had to be completly accessable to the public and anyone could just open images and songs directly without using my app. This was fine for prototyping and launch - but now there is need for a more advances protection against theft.

Don't get me wrong: **I know, that there is no REAL protection.** I just want to give people a hard time when it comes to direct-download. There should be no way to directly link to a media file.

Here is what I came up with:

- **Images and songs are loaded via PHP** - you specify the id as parameter, PHP looks up the location and serves the file, if found. In addition, the file is only served if the nonce provided as parameter is valid (exists and not older than 30 seconds). The nonce is generated by PHP and stored in the `$_SESSION['nonce']` variable.

  `<img src="image/imageid?nonce=[[nonce]]">`
  `<audio><source src="song/songid?nonce=[[nonce]]"></audio>`
- **In my app, I have three functions:**

  - `(string) generateNone()` for generating, session-saving and returning a nonce value -> used in markup to generate the links
  - `(bool) validateNonce()` for checking if a nonce is valid and deleting it afterwards so it cannot be reused
  - `(void) initNonces()` for deleting all nonces from session. This function is called every time the app loads (not including image- and song-serving of course) to prevent accumulation of unused nonces.

---

## The problem:

Theoretically this whole idea works. Practically, I encountered two problems I cannot solve:

1. **Images seem to be reloaded by browser:** When images are changed using jQuery/JavaScript (for example "hide image 1, show image 2" or "hide image 4, show image 5"), the images are not loadable since the nonce is not valid anymore (= was already used once). Stopping nonce-deletion after verification (= nonce is reusable) solves this problem, but this is no real solution. This problem might be related to problem 2, since jQuery only changes CSS-properties to show and hide images.
2. **Images and songs are loaded after nonce lifetime:** The browser seems to load images that are initially hidden by CSS only when the image becomes visible. While this is usually a helpful thing to reduce bandwidth-usage, in my scenario it prevents images and songs from being loaded after the nonce-lifetime of 30 seconds. I need a way to make the browser load everything directly or, at least, open and hold a connetion to the requested image/song within the 30 seconds time span.

## The question:

It is hard to identify the real problem so I hope someone who knows how browsers internally process media-loading can give me a hint on how to fix the described issues. In case you need any code, just let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry for asking and answering just a few minutes later - but I found the solution after hours of searching and I think it might be helpful for someone who comes along similar issues:

I was using jQuery `clone()` / `remove()` to restart the CSS animation of the images. What I didn't know was that this not only duplicated the element, but also reloaded all media within it like it was in the original HTML markup. So the image was being reloaded - causing the problem because the nonce was already used.